# Problem saving the result of a mysql query in a python variable

Tags: python, mysql

I have a code that get the result of a mysql query into a python list and it usually works but sometimes I get the next error: "Index out of range". My code is the next:

I've proved all the possible results of the query and it works, so I dont think that the error is on account of the result of the query

My code is the next:

```py
    cursor.execute("select id_meter from meter where meter_name = %s", meter)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    my_list=[]
    for result in results:
        my_list.append(result[0])
    meter_db = my_list[0]

    #Second query extraction

    cursor.execute("select error_code from error_list where descripcion = %s", mensaje)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    my_list=[]
    for result in results:
        my_list.append(result[0])    #the error is in this line
    codigo = my_list[0]
```

Could be because I use the same list name "my_list[ ]" in both querys?

Comment: Would be nice if you could present us the Traceback. We do not know at what line of code the error is raised.

Comment: I don't have an clear approach to the console right now. But it is safe to assume if error is periodic that issue is that `fetchall` fails -> returning empty string. Which then can not be indexed. Since getting zeroth element of empty list is an `Index error`. So try to use if statement it check if list is result is empty (len == 0) before doing anything else.

Comment: your problem is that you expect every time at least 1 row from the sql statement. You shouldn't assign my_list[0] if you are not sure taht you get an result

Comment: I tried to put a query that I know it isnt in the database and the error that I've got is other than it. But I've put a if condition that compare if .fetchall() give me a empty tuple and solve it...but I need time to get the results